# Force stream based on firestore snapshots to read cache

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to switch from SQLite to Cloud Firestore in my app. And ofcourse, I'm trying to reduce the number of reads from Cloud Firestore.

I get a stream from Cloud Firestore like this:

```
list = fireStore.collection('users')
        .document('public')
        .collection('info').orderBy("date")
        .snapshots();
```

All the documents from the collection 'info' is to be read. When read for the first time, I'd like to force future reads to be from the cache. Until, let's say, 20 days has passed. Then I'd like to update the cache.

This is as I understand it, possible with DocumentReference.get() and Query.get() ([click here to find out how](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-reduce-the-number-of-read-operations-in-cloud-firestore-9f9d6f5a271)), but as far as I have found out, not possible with my solution.

Do I need to change my approach and implement one of the methods above or is there a work around for stream as I've used it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `snapshots` method in FlutterFire is the equivalent of [`onSnapshot` in the native SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen). These methods listen for changes on both the local cache and the server, and cannot be configured otherwise.

The `get()` methods in the native SDKs **and** [FlutterFire](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/get.html) *can* be configured to get the document(s) from a specific source. So if you want to force reading from the local cache, you'll have to use `get(GetOptions(source: Source.cache))`.

An alternative approach could be to [explicitly manage network access](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#disable-and-enable-network-access) for the Firestore client.

Comment: Ok. Is explicitly managing network access frown upon? Seems like a nice 'quick fix' for me and my app...